# TCPView for Android

Tags: applications, internet, resource-monitoring

Someone know if exist a TCPView (windows application) similar app for Android? 
Googling I've found only the use of tcpdump but it's not easy and immediately readable.

Thank for any suggest

Comment: Ok for -1, ok for no comment, but at least tell me if the Q isn't clear or not constructive will be helpfulll for me. No one needs to know what process is connecting and where it connects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not found any app. But using a terminal emulator on a rooted phone with busybox I can use:

netstat -p ( or any other command's argument needed).

Answer (score 1):

I use [TrevE.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17612559&postcount=110). It's not a TCPView replacement. but it has a number of network monitoring tools. I'm suggesting it because it keeps getting better. I started with v6, and now I use v14.

Comment: How this app can help me? Coul you please add in your answer the link to download on Play Store? Thank you